# how to see table structure in JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, ojdbc

I'm new to JDBC,i've doubt,how to see the table structure using jdbc program..give code plese i tried but it showing error my code is

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ram {

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.12:1521:aftdb";


   static final String USER = "system";
   static final String PASS = "manager";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);


      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "desc emp";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      while(rs.next()){

         String emp= rs.getString("emp");


         System.out.println("ID: " + emp);
      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
}
```

but it showing error.please help any one how to get table structure in jdbc program,suggest me

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/ResultSetMetaData-interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation for ResultSetMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Use ResultSetMetadata

Change your sql query

```
sql = "desc emp";
```

as

```
sql = "select * from emp";
```

For example from documentation

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 System.out.println("No. of columns : " + rsmd.getColumnCount());
 System.out.println("Column name of 1st column : " + rsmd.getColumnName(1));
 System.out.println("Column type of 1st column : " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
```

Comment: that is showing table data rite.am thinking about how to see table columns and data types.that's y write that

Comment: @user2854207 view the posted documentation

Comment: ya thanq..can u clarify one more thing please

Comment: If you need *just metadata* you can stripe out data to get zero lines like "... WHERE 1=0"

Comment: how to display the list of table names in my schema using JDBC

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/DatabaseMetaDatagetTablesStringcatalogStringschemaPatternStringtableNamePatternStringtypes.htm

Comment: or otherwise 
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}

Comment: Using `DatabaseMetaData` might be preferable over the use of `ResultSetMetaData`, as the `DatabaseMetaData` provides a lot more information.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to native SELECT statement can be DatabaseMetadata.getColumns
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html